# How to add an individual quantity to a hashmap key and value in java

Tags: java

below i have a program which is a kebab shop menu. it has one problem, i cannot show the quantity correctly of every item. i can show the item and the total price. for example:

i buy 3 chicken burgers and buy one zinger burger. the output is:

```
3 Zinger Burger  2.99
3 Chicken Burger  15.96
```

that is obviously wrong because i only bought 1 Zinger Burger. i believe the problem is that the quantity variable is shared with all hashmap objects.

my desired output would be this:

```
1 Zinger Burger 2.99
3 Chicken Burger 15.96
```

what i need is for every object in the hashmap to have their own individual quantity. the quantity should not be shared with every object

Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Double> menu = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner Obj2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    menu.put("Cheese Burger", 1.99);
    menu.put("Kebab Wrap", 4.99);
    menu.put("Mayo Chicken", 0.99);
    menu.put("Lamb Doner", 3.99);
    menu.put("Biscuits", 1.99);
    menu.put("Ice Cream", 1.49);
    menu.put("Chicken Burger", 3.99);
    menu.put("BBQ Chicken Burger", 3.49);
    menu.put("Zinger Burger", 2.99);



    HashMap<String, Double> list = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    int quantity = 1;

    System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
    String question = Obj.nextLine();
    while (!question.equals("END")) {

    System.out.println("Press 1 to buy an item");
    System.out.println("Press 2 to clear the price and list");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to display all the items with the price");
    int number = Obj.nextInt();
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
    System.out.println("Please name an item: " );   
    String item = Obj2.nextLine();

    if (list.containsKey(item)) {
        quantity += 1;
        list.put(item, list.get(item) + list.get(item));

    }
    else {
        list.put(item, menu.get(item));


    }
    break;
    case 2:
    list.clear();
    System.out.println("The list has now been cleared");
    case 3:
    for (String i : list.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(quantity + " " +  i + " " + " " + list.get(i));
    }
    break;

    }
    System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
    question = Obj.nextLine();
    }




    }
```

Comment: You do not have a unique variable for your orders.  Consider creating an Class that represents your data, e.g. FoodItem which has fields `name` and `price` and then to have an Map of these `Map<FoodItem, Integer>`

Comment: because you are using only one variable always for quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, has already been pointed out, you are using a single `quantity` variable for ALL the items...

```
//...
HashMap<String, Double> list = new HashMap<String, Double>();
int quantity = 1;
//...
switch (number) {
    case 1:
        //...
        if (list.containsKey(item)) {
            quantity += 1;
            list.put(item, list.get(item) + list.get(item));
        }
        //...
        break;
    //...
    case 3:
        for (String i : list.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(quantity + " " +  i + " " + " " + list.get(i));
        }
        break;
}
//...
```

What you really want to do is keep track of the number of times any one item is ordered.

There's a number of ways you could do this, personally, I'd use a couple of Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs), but for simplicity, you could use another `Map`

```
// int quantity = 1;
HashMap<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();
```

What this is going to do, is link the items in the `menu` to an order quantity.

So when an order is placed, you go lookup the quantity from the `order` and (through the magic of auto boxing), increment the value...

```
if (menu.containsKey(item)) {
    Integer quanity = order.get(item);
    if (quanity == null) {
        quanity = 0;
    }
    quanity++;
    order.put(item, quantity);
}
```

And when you're ready, you can just list the order and the items...

```
double tally = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> enrty : order.entrySet()) {
    String name = enrty.getKey();
    int quantity = enrty.getValue();
    double price = menu.get(name);
    double total = quantity * price;
    tally += total;

    System.out.println(quantity + "x " + name + " @ " + price + " = " + total);
}
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, Double> menu = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Obj2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        menu.put("Cheese Burger", 1.99);
        menu.put("Kebab Wrap", 4.99);
        menu.put("Mayo Chicken", 0.99);
        menu.put("Lamb Doner", 3.99);
        menu.put("Biscuits", 1.99);
        menu.put("Ice Cream", 1.49);
        menu.put("Chicken Burger", 3.99);
        menu.put("BBQ Chicken Burger", 3.49);
        menu.put("Zinger Burger", 2.99);

        HashMap<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
        String question = Obj.nextLine();
        while (!question.equals("END")) {

            System.out.println("Press 1 to buy an item");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to clear the price and list");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to display all the items with the price");
            int number = Obj.nextInt();
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please name an item: ");
                    String item = Obj2.nextLine();

                    if (menu.containsKey(item)) {

                        Integer quanity = order.get(item);
                        if (quanity == null) {
                            quanity = 0;
                        }
                        quanity++;
                        order.put(item, quanity);

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    order.clear();
                    System.out.println("The list has now been cleared");
                case 3:

                    double tally = 0;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> enrty : order.entrySet()) {
                        String name = enrty.getKey();
                        int quantity = enrty.getValue();
                        double price = menu.get(name);
                        double total = quantity * price;
                        tally += total;

                        System.out.println(quantity + "x " + name + " @ " + price + " = " + total);
                    }
                    break;

            }
            System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
            question = Obj.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I used your solution and it worked very well. The easiest and simplest solution. Thanks a lot. You're very smart

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

This implementation makes constants out of the menu item labels so they can be reused.

It also includes validation for making sure an item is on the menu and also avoids throwing an InputMismatchException if the user attempts to enter something other than a number when you scan for a number.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    private static final String CHEESEBURGER_LABEL = "Cheese Burger";
    private static final String KEBAB_WRAP_LABEL = "Kebab Wrap";
    private static final String MAYO_CHICKEN_LABEL = "Mayo Chicken";
    private static final String LAMB_DONER_LABEL = "Lamb Doner";
    private static final String BISCUITS_LABEL = "Biscuits";
    private static final String ICE_CREAM_LABEL = "Ice Cream";
    private static final String CHICKEN_BURGER_LABEL = "Chicken Burger";
    private static final String BBQ_CHICKEN_BURGER_LABEL = "BBQ Chicken Burger";
    private static final String ZINGER_BURGER_LABEL = "Zinger Burger";

    private static int getChoice(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Press 1 to buy an item");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to clear the price and list");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to display all the items with the price");
        int number = 0;
        while (number < 1 || number > 3) {
            try {
                number = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                scanner.next();
            }
            if (number < 1 || number > 3) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
            }
        }
        return number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Maps menu item label to menu item price
        Map<String, Double> menu = new HashMap<>();

        Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Obj2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        menu.put(CHEESEBURGER_LABEL, 1.99);
        menu.put(KEBAB_WRAP_LABEL, 4.99);
        menu.put(MAYO_CHICKEN_LABEL, 0.99);
        menu.put(LAMB_DONER_LABEL, 3.99);
        menu.put(BISCUITS_LABEL, 1.99);
        menu.put(ICE_CREAM_LABEL, 1.419);
        menu.put(CHICKEN_BURGER_LABEL, 3.99);
        menu.put(BBQ_CHICKEN_BURGER_LABEL, 3.49);
        menu.put(ZINGER_BURGER_LABEL, 2.99);

        // Maps menu item label to menu item count
        Map<String, Integer> order = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
        String question = Obj.nextLine();
        while (!question.equals("END")) {
            int number = getChoice(Obj);
            switch (number) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please name an item: ");
                    String item = Obj2.nextLine();

                    if (!menu.containsKey(item)) {
                        System.out.println(item + " is not on the menu!");
                        break;
                    }

                    int menuItemCount = (order.containsKey(item)) ? order.get(item) + 1 : 1;
                    order.put(item, menuItemCount);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    order.clear();
                    System.out.println("The order has now been cleared");
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Your current order:\n");
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> itemCount : order.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(itemCount.getValue() + " " + itemCount.getKey()
                                + " " + menu.get(itemCount.getKey()) * itemCount.getValue());
                    }
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Write STOP to stop the program. Otherwise, press enter");
            question = Obj.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```